# How I can make a column with some indicator?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 4 indicator and an id row. How I can make a column with respect of this indicator like this:

```
  ID.   col1.   col2.   col3.   col4. 
   1      1       0       0       0
   2      0       0       0       1
   3      0       0       1       0
```

I n each row just one of the columns is 1 and others 0. new column is 1 if col1 is 1, is 2 if col2 is 1 , is 3 if col3 is 1 and is 4 if col4 is 1.

so the output is

```
  ID.   col.    
   1      1      
   2      4      
   3      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `max.col`

```
cbind(df1[1], `col.` = max.col(df1[-1], "first"))
#    ID. col.
#1   1    1
#2   2    4
#3   3    3
```

---

If there are no 1s in the rows, create a logical condition to return that row as `NA`

```
df1[2, 5] <- 0
cbind(df1[1], `col.` =  max.col(df1[-1], "first") * NA^ !rowSums(df1[-1] == 1))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID. = 1:3, col1. = c(1L, 0L, 0L), col2. = c(0L, 
0L, 0L), col3. = c(0L, 0L, 1L), col4. = c(0L, 1L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```